# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '123.avi'

Tags: python

I´m writting a script to send emails form a raspberry pi 4 and I want to attach a file to an email via python, but i always get this error.

I´m pretty new to python. I know that the file is in the right place and I tried some other files. I tried the full path of the file. I read a lot of other similar questions, but with no luck

```
filename = '123.avi'
attachmet = open(filename,'rb')

part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
part.set_payload(attachment.read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+filename)

msg.attach(part)
```

without this lines the script works fine.
I get the mail.

but with this lines I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Monitor/sendmail.py", line 31, in <module>
    attachmet = open(filename,'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '123.avi'
```

Comment: The script is expecting 123.avi to exist in the directory the script is being executed in.

Comment: The file has to be in the working path. That can be another path than the one where your Python script is. You might want to use an absolute file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me.

```
with open(full_path_of_file, "rb") as fs:
    part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(fs.read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=os.path.basename(full_path_of_file))
msg.attach(part)
```